# How to get the results from multiple tables join using single query in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: mysql, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have to fetch the data from multiple tables by joining them using NativeQuery like below:

```
    String query = "Select ad.* from address_data ad inner join address a ON a.ad_id = ad.ad_id where address = :address";
    Query q = entityManager.createNativeQuery(query, AddressData.class);
    q.setParameter("address", address);

    List<AddressData> permitList = q.getResultList();
```

On testing the code, 2 queries are created to fetch the data.

1. to get the data from address_data table
2. to get the data from address table

How can I get only one query to fetch the data ?

Comment: Could you specify which db vendor, jpa vendor and app server are you using?

Comment: @PabloBastidas I am using db vendor=mysql, spring Data JPA, spring boot embedded tomcat server.

Answer (score 0):

In most cases you want your relationship to be lazy fetched `fetch=FetchType.LAZY` so your list is only loaded when you explicitly call it.

With that being said you can initialize a lazy association this way:

```
@Query("select ad from address_data ad inner join fetch a.addresss a where a.address = :address")
List<AddressData> methodName(@Param("address") String address);
```

There is no need of a native query for this. You can define a repository for your Entity and add the above method to it.

Here's a more detailed explanation on [Fetch Strategy](https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-facts-the-importance-of-fetch-strategy/). 
You also might want to check the Spring Data JPA documentation on [repositories](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/1.9.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#repositories).

BTW you should post your Entities as well.

Comment: For that simple example you do not need native query, however lets say I need to use WITH RECURSION in PostgreSQL. I want a single query with join fetch. Currently the workaround for this is creating a view.